# Standard for Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Does the Clojure language have a standard put out by an organization?

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is important.  Is there a corporate policy somewhere saying only standardized languages will be accepted?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a standard for the language and if there was then who was approving and keeping it up to date.

Comment: It's important when you are trying to decide if some code is correct. Say the code depends on the fact that `keys` and `vals` return the keys and values of a map in the same order. That makes sense and works in the current implementation, but a standard would say if it's guaranteed to work in all conforming implementations.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it does not.

It's an [open-source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/), [BDFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_Dictator_For_Life) driven language, with [Rich Hickey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Hickey) being the BDFL.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing to a grammar for clojure would be the reader:

http://clojure.org/reader